# Choosing an array with a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu in HTML:

```
<select id="list" onchange="getSelectValue();">
    <option value ="car1">Audi A2</option>
    <option value ="car2">Audi A3</option>
    <option value ="car3">BMW 1 F20</option>
    <option value ="car4">Opel Corsa</option>
</select>
```

For getting the value of the `<select>`, I have this function:

```
function getSelectValue()
{
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
    console.log(selectedValue); 
}
```

In another script, I have many arrays:

```
var car1 =[1, 5, 6, 7];
var car2 =[4, 6, 8, 3];
var car3 =[6, 7, 3, 4];
var car4 =[3, 7, 2, 1];
```

If the user has chosen e.g. car 2 in the dropdown menu, the array car2 shall be selected. And now e.g. values of this array should be added. How can I do this?

```
document.write(car[1]+car[3]);
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working. Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, you can use an object. The selected value is the key of the object, and then at the key is the array you want, like this:

```js
var carData = {
  "car1": [1, 5, 6, 7],
  "car2": [4, 6, 8, 3],
  "car3": [6, 7, 3, 4],
  "car4": [3, 7, 2, 1]
};

function getSelectValue() {
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
  console.log(selectedValue);
  console.log(carData[selectedValue]);
}
```

```html
<select id="list" onchange="getSelectValue();">
  <option value="car1">Audi A2</option>
  <option value="car2">Audi A3</option>
  <option value="car3">BMW 1 F20</option>
  <option value="car4">Opel Corsa</option>
</select>
```